# 'str' object has no attribute 'META'

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, render

I am getting the error:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'META'

The Traceback highlights this bit of code:

```
return render('login.html', c)
```

Where that bit of code is in my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect    # allows us to redirect the browser to a difference URL
from django.contrib import auth                 # checks username and password handles login and log outs
from django.core.context_processors import csrf # csrf - cross site request forgery. 

def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render('login.html', c)
```

This is what my template looks like:

```
{% extends "base.html"%}

{% block content %}

    {% if form.errors %}
        <p class = 'error'>Sorry, that's not a valid username or password</p>
    {% endif %}

    <form action = '/accounts/auth/' method = 'post'> {% csrf_token %}
        <label for = 'username'>User name: </label>
        <input type = 'text' name = 'username' value = '' id = 'username'>
        <label for = 'password'>Password: </label>
        <input type = 'password' name = 'password' value = '' id = 'password'>

        <input type = 'submit' value = 'login'>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I assume I might be using `render()` incorrectly but in the docs I think I am putting in the correct parameters.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First parameter to `render()` is `request` object, so update your line to

```
return render(request, 'login.html', c)
```

It is trying to refer `request.META`, but you are passing `'login.html'` string, hence that error.

Comment: ugh how did i not see this...it's getting late. Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks. In my case I put quotes around request, duh!  
    `return render('request', "gameplay/game_detail.html", {'game': game})`

Answer (score 0):

Correct code is

```
  return render(request,'login.html', c)
```

for example

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home_page_view(request):
    return render(request,'testapp/home.html')
```

Reference link:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'META'

Because I used [@stringfilter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#template-filters-that-expect-strings) for `test()` and rendered `index.html` in it as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

@stringfilter # Here
def test(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

So, I removed `@stringfilter` from `test()` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

# @stringfilter # Here
def test(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this mistake is very uncommon, yet I made it. Hence I am stating it here so that noone else makes that mistake. I passed my request parameter as a String.

```py
return render('request', 'login.html', c) 
#Wrong
```

What I should have done instead is that I should have removed the quotes around request.

```py
return render(request, 'login.html', c) 
#Correct
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exact error message. And this is how I fixed that

#### before

#### views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, username, password) #this is wrong
            messages.success(request,"You are now logged in")
            return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Your credentials invalid")
            return redirect('login')

     return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
```

#### after

#### views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
       if user is not None:
           auth.login(request, user) # this is correct
           messages.success(request,"You are now logged in")
           return redirect('dashboard')
       else:
           messages.error(request, "Your credentials invalid")
           return redirect('login')

    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
```

Notice that I made a mistake there by adding username and password on the first code, and I fixed that on the second code

Comment: This is pretty hard to read... we need to mentally diff two blocks of code that aren't even lined up beside each other. Please consider showing just _one_ code block, e.g. maybe a correct one with the incorrect line commented out and clearly marked.

Answer (score -1):

```
def get(self, request,pk, *args, **kwargs):
    emp=Emp.objects.get(id=pk)
```

#here after json if we take like these without 'single quotes it wont rise error

```
emp_data=serialize('json',[emp],fields=('ename','esal','eadres'))
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?